# Unable to mount exfat-formatted external HDD on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu and I now cannot access my external HDD that I formatted in my previous Ubuntu install (same version of Ubuntu), and so I am quite confused. When I attempt to mount it says:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYxD6.png)

[My disks view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVuU5.png)

I tried installing exfat-fuse and exfat-utils ([guide here](https://low-orbit.net/error-mounting-unknown-filesystem-type-exfat))but that doesn't seemed to have worked either. I did not do this previously, on my other installation so I'm really a bit puzzled at what the issue is.